# How to run pyleus on Storm

Tags: python, apache-storm, pyleus

I'm a learning on Storm, I have installed zookeeper, storm, python and pyleus. the first step, I copy python script from pyleus web as a sample (https://github.com/Yelp/pyleus/tree/aaa423864f953332202832b8fd8404e03d3d74e3 ) and try to run it in storm server, the sample include below 3 files:
pyleus_topology.yaml, dummy_spout.py and dummy_bolt.py
the 2 py file has been put into a folder namely "my_first_topology" but when I run the pyleus build command in my VMware server(CentOS64-bit), the command can run 20 second and then, I got below error:

> *[root@localhost bin]# pyleus build /root/Desktop/CRM_ETL-Project-Storm/my_first_topology/pyleus_topology.yaml
>   pyleus build: error: [VirtualenvError] Failed to execute Python
>   module: my_first_topology.dummy_spout. Error:
>   /tmp/tmpZMIXa3/resources/pyleus_venv/bin/python: No module named
>   my_first_topology*

what I can do for it? any steps I missed?

the script for reference
1> pyleus_topology.yaml

name: my_first_topology

topology:

```
- spout:
    name: my-first-spout
    module: my_first_topology.dummy_spout
- bolt:
    name: my-first-bolt
    module: my_first_topology.dummy_bolt
    groupings:
        - shuffle_grouping: my-first-spout
```

2> dummy_spout.py

from pyleus.storm import Spout

class DummySpout(Spout):

```
OUTPUT_FIELDS = ['sentence', 'name']
def next_tuple(self):
    self.emit(("This is a sentence.", "spout",))
```

if **name** == '**main**':
    DummySpout().run()

3> dummy_bolt.py

from pyleus.storm import SimpleBolt

class DummyBolt(SimpleBolt):

```
OUTPUT_FIELDS = ['sentence']
def process_tuple(self, tup):
    sentence, name = tup.values
    new_sentence = "{0} says, \"{1}\"".format(name, sentence)
    self.emit((new_sentence,), anchors=[tup])
```

if **name** == '**main**':
    DummyBolt().run()

Comment: did you created .pyleus.conf in /home/your_user/?

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you are missing an empty file named "__init.py__" in your inner my_first_topology folder. That file makes it a python module. Just create it and you should be set.